# Unable to send sms messages using Amazon SNS from cloud server when message contains the string devCollector.local:

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, verizon

Amazon SNS fails to send SMS messages from a cloud server when the body of the message contains the following string: `devCollector.local:` and the AWS dashboard logs display, `Phone carrier has blocked this message`.

Because of the error, I assumed that the carrier for the phone I was using to test notifications (Verizon) was blocking the message so I attempted with a Google voice number and got the same result. After some troubleshooting I found that if I removed the `.` delimiter and changed the message body to `devCollector (local):` the SMS notification would go through without issue. The message is being sent via a JS script using `Node.js v14.19.1`

I can send the following string in the message body: `jeremy-crow.local` from my local machine without issue to both my test phone ( carrier: Verizon ) and to a Google voice number using the same script running `Node.js v14.18.3`.

Something else worth noting is that I can send the offending string from my phone directly to my Google voice number and vice versa, which is further evidence that it's related to Amazon SNS (or both carrier's treatment of SNS).

I'd like to know why the presence of the string `devCollector.local` in the message body when sending SMS messages through Amazon SNS from an Azure cloud server is causing the messages to fail so that I can avoid this in the future (and hopefully help others to avoid the issue as well). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Many phone carriers block SMS payloads that contain things that look like URLs. More information is available here: https://support.text-em-all.com/article/572-sending-urls-in-text-messages# ("carrier spam filters will detect invalid URLs and block messages containing them").

These types of spam filters are often more stringent for messages coming from businesses, which is why traffic from AWS and Azure might be getting blocked, but a SMS from your phone isn't.